# How To Use UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have a button on a viewControler that I want to bring up a UIDatePicker.  I think I will need to animate it in/out.

So far I have the button setup and have the UIDatePicker in my IB in a separate view.  I think having it come up modally would make the most sense.

What code is necessary to link the UIDatePicker to slide into view with the click of the button, then slide out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to maintain a reference to your UIDatePicker and then you can use `UIView` to animate the datePicker in and out. I would wrap the picker in a UIView so you can add a hide button or associated controls.

**In your header file:**

```
@interface MyControllerWithSlidingDatePicker : UIViewController{

  //If you use Interface builder, use this
  IBOutlet IDatePicker *picker; 
  //If you aren't using IB, use this
  //UIDatePicker *picker; 

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker *picker;

@end
```

**And your implementation file:**

```
#import "MyControllerWithSlidingDatePicker.h"

@implementation MyControllerWithSlidingDatePicker

  - (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
       //If you use Interface Builder, skip this part.

       UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
       //Configure your picker

       self.picker = dp;

       [dp release];

    }

    return self;  
  }

 - (IBAction)slidePickerIn{
   //Position the picker out of site
   [self.picker setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height,self.width,self.picker.frame.size.height];

   //Add the picker to the view
   [self.view addSubview:self.picker];

   //This animation will work on iOS 4
   //For older iOS, use "beginAnimation:context"
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

      [self.datePicker setFrame:CGRectMake0,self.view.frame.size.height-self.datePicker.frame.size.height,self.datePicker.frame.size.width,self.datePicker.frame.size.height];

   }  

 }

 - (void)dealloc{
   [picker release];
   [super dealloc];
 }

@end
```

To animate out, you just make another method to change the frame to original "offscreen" frame.

Comment: Thanks Moshe, I'm going to try implementing this now.  But one question: I would just call the `slidePickerIn` method when the button is clicked to initiate this new datepicker view, right?

Comment: The datepicker is set up in the init method. It is the same datepicker the whole time. You can theoretically create a new one each time, but then you have to maintain a reference to it the whole time, so you can hide it again.

Comment: What I mean is that I have a button on my view, when I click the button, only then do I want to see the datePicker.  And when I select the date, the picker should go away and I would be back to my original view.

Comment: Hang on. @Faisal, can you come to the SO chat room?

Comment: Sure, im in the iOS chatroom now.

Answer (score 16):

You could save yourself the trouble and set your UIDatePicker as the "keyboard" for your UITextField. Like so:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
self.dateField.inputView = datePicker;
```

This way it acts just like a keyboard and animates in and out as needed. You use the textField delegate methods to tell it to go away. The easy way is hard enough. That's my philosophy ;)

Comment: Ya totally agree with you @Matjan

Comment: @erdemgc, try calling "resignFirstResponder" on the inputView

Comment: Nice idea, except that you cannot close the picker. :(